# pandas merge and groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 pandas dataframes which look like below.

Data Frame 1:

```
Section    chainage_from     chainage_to     Frame  
R125R002    10.133            10.138          1  
R125R002    10.138            10.143          2  
R125R002    10.143            10.148          3  
R125R002    10.148            10.153          4  
R125R002    10.153            10.158          5
```

Data Frame 2:

```
Section Chainage    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   
R125R002    10.133  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.134  1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.135  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.136  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.137  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.138  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.139  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.14   5   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.141  1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.142  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.143  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.144  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.145  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.146  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.147  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.148  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.149  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.15   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.151  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.152  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.153  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
```

required output dataframe:

```
Section Chainage Frame  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   
R125R002    10.133  1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.138  2   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.143  3   6   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.148  4   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0     
R125R002    10.153  5   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
```

Dataframe 2 has the increment of 1 m intervals while dataframe 1 has the increment of 5 m. I would like to merge dataframe 2 to dataframe 1 between chainage_from and chainage_to  and apply group by. Groupby for column 1 is sum, column 2 max, colum3 to 8 average.

In SQL, I would link section between 2 frames and apply between the condition for the chainage from and to and then add groupby.
Is there any way to achieve this in pandas.

Answer (score 1):

merge the dataframes by `Section` and filter so that `Chainage` is in [from & to).

```
merged = pd.merge_asof(df2, df1, by='Section', left_on='Chainage', right_on='chainage_from')
```

groupby & aggregate, passing a dictionary that maps column name & aggregate function to use.

```
merged.groupby(['Section', 'chainage_from', 'Frame'], as_index=False).agg(
    {'1': 'sum', '2': 'max', '3': 'mean', '4': 'mean',
     '5': 'mean', '6': 'mean', '7': 'mean', '8': 'mean'}
)
```

outputs:

```
    Section  chainage_from  Frame  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
0  R125R002         10.133      1  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
1  R125R002         10.138      2  6  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
2  R125R002         10.143      3  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
3  R125R002         10.148      4  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
4  R125R002         10.153      5  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: FYI, this will create large dataframe ..

Comment: @Wen, thanks, i realized there was a better merge option available, see updated answer

Comment: Much better  upvote

Answer (score 0):

We can using `IntervalIndex` to create the interval , then using `.loc` to get the `df2` value in `df1`'s position ,and assign the Frame columns , then we create the dict with columns' name with different function , using `agg` to achieve what you need

```
idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(left = df1.chainage_from,right = df1.chainage_to,closed = 'left')
df1.index = idx

df2['Frame'] = df1.loc[df2.Chainage].Frame.values

d = {'Chainage':'first','1':'sum','2':'max'}

d.update(dict(zip(list('345678'),['mean']*6)))

s = df2.groupby(['Section','Frame'],as_index = False).agg(d)
s
Out[294]: 
    Section  Frame  6  7  2  1  5  3  8  4  Chainage
0  R125R002      1  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0    10.133
1  R125R002      2  0  0  0  6  0  1  0  0    10.138
2  R125R002      3  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0    10.143
3  R125R002      4  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0    10.148
4  R125R002      5  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0    10.153
```